# Collapse/Expand Swagger Response Model Class

Tags: javascript, jquery, swagger, swagger-ui

I'm using Swagger API documentation for my rest services. I have successfully integrated Swagger with my code and it works.

But I have a requirement to format the Swagger UI. Since the number of response classes are many in my project, the Swagger page looks very lengthy and the user has to scroll down a lot to view information.

So I want to collapse my response model classes and expand it when the user clicks the class. Is there a way to do it and if so where and what changes have to be made. I tried editing the Swagger-UI.js file but I could not achieve the needed output.

Please let me know and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

swagger-ui has the parameter [docExpansion](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/2880478030ed5204a3fcf67ada6d26a643262cdf/docs/usage/configuration.md#parameters). Default is `list`, but if set it to `none` in the defaults section in `src/core/index.js` :

`docExpansion: "none"`

it will work and collapse everything when loading the site.

Answer (score 0):

Swagger-UI.js is generated it would be very hard to modify Swagger UI by modifying this file.

If you want to customize SwaggerUI you should clone the github repository https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/ then modify files and rebuild it (you will then get a modified Swagger-UI.js and all other files).

Swagger-UI is composed of different views, each view having a js file and a handlebars template.
In your use case I'll try to modify these files:

- src/main/template/signature.handlebars
- src/main/javascript/view/SignatureView.js

Answer (score 0):

To collapse swagger ui by default, you can use :

```
app = FastAPI(
swagger_ui_parameters = {"docExpansion":"none"},
...
)
```

Answer (score 0):

for collapse all endpoints by default:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const swaggerUi = require('swagger-ui-express');
const swaggerDoc = require('./swagger-output.json');

app.use('/doc', swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(swaggerDoc, false, { docExpansion: 'none' }));
```